# Why does Paginate (pr) cut off text prematurely when columnating it?

Tags: bash, pagination

This is a really frustrating error, and I can't figure out why.

I'm trying to use ls print out ever filename, and the full path to that file beside it, so as to have that information as two columns. the file extension is .faa

I've tried `ls -1 $PWD/*.faa *.faa | pr -tr -2` 
which gives me

`file1.faa /directory/file`

`file2.faa /directory/file`

`file3.faa /directory/file`

It's literally cutting off the file name in the second column, and I don't understand why. I just needed a simple columnator, but why isn't this working?

Comment: I'm not sure that "why" is not really a productive question. The fact is, `pr` *does* truncate the data to fit inside the columns (by default), and is documented as doing so, and that's that. A more productive approach is to describe the behavior that you want instead, and asking how you can achieve that.

Comment: So, expected behavior is to columnate normally. Is there a way to make it not cut off?

Comment: How do you define "columnate normally"? `pr` does have a `-J` flag that prevents truncation, but it also means the columns won't line up perfectly. You might also try `column` instead of `pr`; `column` makes its own decisions about how many columns there should be, based on the desired width. Or, if you have your own precise definition of "columnate normally", you can write your own implementation. It's not so hard to columnate in any way you might want; the difficulty is in figuring out what you want.

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly the text manipulation I was looking for. I was that -J wasnt part of my --help

Answer (score 1):

With GNU find:

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.faa' -printf "%f %p\n"
```